# Updating to Pylons 0.10

Tags: pylons

In the instruction (http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/upgrading/) I find :

> To upgrade to 1.0, first upgrade your
>   project to 0.10. This is a Pylons
>   release that is fully
>   backwards-compatible with 0.9.7.
>   However under 0.10 a variety of
>   warnings will be issued about the
>   various things that need to be changed
>   before upgrading to 1.0.

What warnings? The ones from easy_install? I get this from easy_install (I have cut away some stuff I know is not warnings).

```
easy_install -U http://pylonshq.com/download/0.10/Pylons-0.10.tar.gz
Downloading http://pylonshq.com/download/0.10/Pylons-0.10.tar.gz
Processing Pylons-0.10.tar.gz
Running Pylons-0.10/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-mGVgCf/Pylons-0.10/egg-dist-tmp-H1Lklt
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'tests/test_units/session'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.hgignore' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.hgtags' found anywhere in distribution
```

If these are the warnings the instruction talks about I need some help understanding them. What do they mean?

If these are not the warnings the instruction talks about I need some directions. When will I get these warnings the instruction talks about?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented unit and function tests according to the [testing chapter in the Pylons book](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/testing.html). During this process I found all things that I needed to change after the upgrade to 0.10.

So there are two ways of finding all warnings that need to be dealt with after upgrading to 0.10 and before upgrading to Pylons 1.0.

1. Start a paster server and manually surf your pylons app looking for warnings in the paster output.
2. Be smart and create your unit and function tests according to the [Pylons book](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/testing.html) and run them to find all warnings.

Answer (score 1):

These warnings only saying that the during Pylons upgrade (not your application) "easy_install" found some files that were in the previous distribution of Pylons (in directory) and which are not included in new package.

For example ".DS_Store" is a hidden file created by MacOSX to store some attributes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) and probably it was not created during  installation.

Warnings mentioned in the documentation, are warnings that appear on the console when you start your application with a new Pylons and there you should look for upgrade hints (for example information about depreciations).

I think that ones are meaningless for your upgrade process.

Hope it helps...

Comment: What do you mean "warnings that appear on the console when you start your application". Do you mean when I run it in paster serve?

Comment: Yes, e.g. "DeprecationWarning: The egg:PasteScript#flup_fcgi_thread entry point is deprecated; please use egg:Flup#fcgi_thread instead"